# Taking mean of multiple column values by month and year Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, date, dataframe

I'd like to use this data:

```
Date            Producer         Hour          Product Rate
01-01-2001      Hamilton          0                 560
01-01-2001      Hamilton          1                 540
01-01-2001      Hamilton          2                 510
01-01-2001      Hamilton          3                 590
01-01-2001      Hamilton          4                 600
.
.
.
01-01-2001      Hamilton          23                150
01-02-2001      Hamilton          0                 510
01-02-2001      Hamilton          1                 530
01-02-2001      Hamilton          2                 540
.
.
.
01-01-2001      Checker          0                  150
01-01-2001      Checker          1                  260
01-01-2001      Checker          2                  256
01-01-2001      Checker          3                  360
```

I'd like to get an average by **Hour** and **Producer** of the **Production Rate** based off each **Date Monthly/Annually**.

This would mean we group on not only Hour and Producer but the month and year.

I can't figure out an easy way to do this with a large dataset. I've tried:

```
data_avg = data.groupby([lambda x: x.year, lambda x: x.month]).mean()
```

But I don't want to simply copy and paste lambda code without knowing fully how it works or how to use it.

Is there an easier way to filter by `groupby` for what I need? I've changed the dates to datetime format so it's a matter of grouping now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also do this by simply using `groupby` as below:

```
data_avg = data.groupby([data['Date'].dt.year.rename('year'), data['Date'].dt.month.rename('month'), data['Hour']])['Product Rate'].mean()
```

Comment: @HelloToEarth, check it now please. I edited my anwser. There was one missing bracket  [] for the list inside groupby

Comment: This creates an index like (2010, 1, 0, 'Hamilton') where the first entry is the year, second is month, third is hour, and fourth is the producer. Is there a way I can just have these each as actual columns produced rather than grouped into an index like this?

Comment: This converts into a series but when I take the series into a dataframe using `data_avg.to_frame` it automatically parses out the index into the respective columns.